# select all columns from 2 tables having duplicated columns

Tags: sql, firebird

I have 2 tables `Customer` and `Customer_address` connected by a `customer_code` column.

I need to create a select query to bring all columns from both tables. The problem is that I need to use aliases for the duplicated columns.

I tried:

```
select * from Customer left join Customer_address on Customer.customer_code=Customer_address.customer_code
```

Not working as expected. How can I avoid the duplicated without having to type all columns ?

Comment: Consider not using `*` and instead specifying the columns explicitly.

Comment: Hi Mark, that will not be practical for me cuz there are too many columns in the original dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only duplicate column name is the one used for the `JOIN`, you can use the `USING` clause:

```
select *
from Customer c left join
     Customer_address ca
     using (customer_code);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon ! Awesome.

Comment: In Postgresql (and probably in other SQL dialects) this works no matter how many columns are duplicated. Columns from the second table simply have the number '1' appended to them.